# Can I use jinja2 for naming variables in HTML?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

preferences.html

```
<form>
{% block content %}
    {% for tag in tags %}
        <!--Checking tag category-->
        {{% if tag.category == "food" %}}
            <input type="checkbox" id={{tag.tag}} name={{tag.tag}} value={{tag.tag}}>
            <label for={{tag.tag}}> {{tag.tag}} </label><br>
        {{% endif %}}
    {{% endfor %}}
{% endblock %}
</form>
```

Can the **id={{tag.tag}}** statement work or are there some other alternatives?

I've tried it and got some jinja exception errors

Comment: In general, yes this can work.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: The statement syntax is `{% ... %}`, not `{{% ... %}}`. (`if`, `endif`, ...)

Comment: And I think you should wrap the attribute value in quotes (`id="{{tag.tag}}"`)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if its typo or its the code u are testing against. jinja templating engine is particular between logic / conditions / statements `{% for item in navigation %}` which uses `{% %}` single `{}` and variables / expressions `{{ varaible.attribute }}` which uses double `{{ }}`. you can read up more from the documentation [link](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/).

Comment: Yes it was a typo, I found it too.
{% %} instead of {{% %}} for navigation worked out for me